# When install Python3.5 kernel to Jupyter Notebook, confirming the ssl certificate issue

Tags: python, ssl, kernel, certificate, jupyter-notebook

On my Macbook Pro, I use Anaconda Navigator 1.8.2. for Python2 when I installed it.

**I use I've used this link**, successfully install a 
python3.6 Kernel into jupyter notebook. :https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

**I try the same procedure, by changing python3 to python3.5** (3.6.4 and 3.5.4 respectively if you call which python3 or python3.5 on my mac). Note that the python 3.5 is just downloaded and installed few hours ago from: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-354/
and I chose: Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit installer, to complete the installation

**Then I do the following as instructed by Ipython Document**: run `python3.5 -m pip install ipykernel` in terminal

**But error goes:**

Collecting ipykernel

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ipykernel/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for ipykernel

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

**Then I try to upgrade the pip by running this code in terminal**: `python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

**But there is still error:**
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

**It looks like it's the python3.5's problem**, but right now I have no idea what's going on under the hood. If you know how to solve it, please share with me. Thank you

Comment: Why are you mixing Anaconda with the standard distribution? The whole point  Anaconda and the `conda` is to serve as an environment management system that deals with installing different interpreters for you...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed Conda could create virtual environment with python 3.5. But I need to use python 3.5 in jupyter notebook, which requires `python3 -m pip install ipykernel` to be installed

Comment: So? You can manage that all with `conda`. Adding a bunch of non-managed interpreter installs to your system is a great way to much things up.

Comment: So, the [docs you link to have an example of just that](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Mac terminal, try to upgrade pip as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Your issue seems to be related to the recent TLS deprecation for pip. Python.org sites are stopping support for TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703) if you'd like to know more details.

Comment: Interesting find.

Comment: May I ask, as I have python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 under Versions folder. When implement that, what which python's pip get upgraded?

Comment: A broader question is that I could use `python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip` for python2.7 and  `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` for python3.6, but I cannot use `python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade pip` for python 3.5

Comment: Oh I got it, by changing `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python` to `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.5` and I could `python3.5 -m pip install ipykernel`. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jason Also, using a virtual environment will make your life much easier. It's meant to prevent these kind of version conflicts.

Comment: @Anupam Could you share how to make it also available to jupyter notebook? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jason - do you mean creating a virtual env? Please see this: http://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/