# Not one package working in Python

Tags: python

For around a week or two now, I've been trying to get certain packages working, and I've tried almost everything.

I've tried using pip, and pip3 when installing packages
I've tried re-installing python 32 bit and 64 bit
I've tried different versions of python
I've tried different versions of the packages

Some of the things I've tried to install are things like pygame and opengl

Please help me with this

Comment: which version do you have installed now? Which platform (Windows/Linux/Mac)? Do you get any specific errors?

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home, I have Python 3.6 64 bit, and the error I get most of the time is  "no module named 'whatever module im getting'"

Comment: Without any details about the problem or error messages there is no way we could give qualified help.

Comment: That is the error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Answer (score 0):

This official link has information regarding installation of packages
     https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#use-pip-for-installing

Steps:

```
1. Download `get-pip.py` file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. Install pip - python get-pip.py
3. Then install any packages using pip - pip install <package>
```

Comment: I tried 'pip install 'pygame~=3.6'  and it said that pip was outdated, so I got pip 10.0.0 and now there's a fatal error whenever I try to get anything.

Comment: The package pygame with version 3.6 is not available. I got "No matching distribution found for pygame==3.6
". Did you tried with other packages ?

Comment: I still get a fatal error. Though, I'm going to re-install python and try again.

Comment: I re-installed python and tried to install PyOpenGL instead, and still got a fatal error.

Comment: Try the steps mentioned above which I have followed in my machine. This definitely works !!

Comment: ..How do I download get-pip.py?

Comment: Open this URL: `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`. Right click and select 'Save as' and save the file as 'get-pip.py'.

Comment: It says "ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command: C:\Users\my name\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -m pip"