# Pip SSL error on Mac

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I keep getting this SSL error when using pip on my mac. I have done a fresh install of the OS and it hasn't made any different. Turning the firewall off also doesn't make any difference. Anyone got any ideas?

Here's the error:

```
> Seans-Mac-mini:~ seanhatch$ pip3 install discord.py
Collecting discord.py
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/discord-py/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord.py (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for discord.py
```

Discord.py was used as an example but it doesn't work for any packages.

Comment: Strange that it happens using Python3. How did you install Python? Which version are you using exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)