# Problems with both pip3 and pip install Mac os X

Tags: python, pip

i'm having trouble downloading libraries using pip (never had this problem before, just started a week or two ago)..

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >> get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

I've also tried the following solution

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org <package_name>
```

but that doesnt work either unfortunately. The error i'm getting is as follows:

```
Collecting pycoin
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycoin/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycoin (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pycoin
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: I would say this question is not a duplicate of the linked question, as this question addresses the issue of upgrading multiple python versions on macOS, which requires a different solution than those available in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, in that I could upgrade pip for my macOS system Python (version 2.7) following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/6881890), but it wouldn't work for any versions of Python 3. Here's an adapted version of that other SO answer that worked for me:

1. Open up terminal and get the python file that installs pip (since we can't use pip itself) and save it as "get-pip.py": `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py >> get-pip.py`
2. Upgrade pip for your OS's python version: `python get-pip.py` (You'll probably need to run it with `sudo`.)
3. Upgrade pip for Python 3: `python3 get-pip.py` (This assumes you have Python 3 symlinked as "python3". If you don't you'll need to provide the full path to your Python 3 version.)

Then you should be good to go! (Check with `pip --version`, `pip3 --version`, and/or `pip2 --version`.)