# pip install not working on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Celery using pip, but it's throwing me the below error. I tried to install some other packages but it resulted in the same error as mentioned below.

```
> pip install Celery



Error: 


    Collecting Celery
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Celery (from versions: 
      )
      No matching distribution found for Celery.
```

I am using **ubuntu 16.04** on **oracle virtual box 5.2.2** and **python 2.7.14**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Answer (score 3):

Use `pip install celery`, without capital letters as seen on https://pypi.org/project/celery/.

Comment: PyPI packages names are case-insensitive. `Celery` and `celery` are the same package.