# How can I fix pip install certificate issue on Windows with Python 2.7?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip

In Windows, I have Python 2.7 installed. I am using this version of Python in my virtual environment. When I try pip install with anything I get the following kinds of errors stating that I do not have a valid security certificate.

> c:\projects\scrubbed\scrubbed\env\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339:
>   SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI
>   (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this
>   platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS
>   certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a
>   newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>   SNIMissingWarning
>   c:\projects\scrubbed\scrubbed\env\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>   InsecurePlatformWarning   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)':
>   /simple/certifi/
>   c:\projects\scrubbed\scrubbed\env\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137:
>   InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
>   This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
>   certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
>   Python to solve this. For more information, see
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

I don't have these problems with a Python 3.6.5 virtual environment. Unfortunately, I need to use Python 2.7 for Google App Engine development.

My requirements.txt file includes the following:

```
Flask>=0.12
Flask-Cors>=3.0.3
flask-restplus>=0.10.1
google-api-python-client>=1.6.5
GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient>=1.9.22.1
```

I am interested in any fixes at this point. I have tried just about everything I have found on StackOverflow.

**Edit** 
This is has been identified as a possible duplication of the question, ["...Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063). These error messages were however quite different. My actual fix was to completely install Python 2.7.14, downloaded from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line in your error:

```
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)':
```

Python.org sites have recently stopped support for TLS v1.0 and v1.1

Try upgrading pip as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

You can still use Python 2.7 once you upgrade `pip` since it will then use the later TLS version (i.e >=1.2)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703) for more details.

Comment: I installed Python 2.7.14. I'm not sure what version of 2.7.x I had before, but now I can run pip install in the 2.7 virtual environment.

Comment: I noted that my actual method of updating to Python 2.7.14 differed in my edit of the original question.

Comment: For me it was upgrading actual python for Windows by downloading and running the installer

Comment: it doesn't work for me @anupam

Comment: I confirm upgrading python version to 2.7.15 fixes the problem. (before I had python 2.7.9 and updating pip as suggested gave the same TLS error) now pip runs as expected

Comment: @serguitus Thanks. I upgraded my python 2.7.3 and solved problem.

Comment: @Jiwon, glad to help