# pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)

Tags: ssl, pip, pypi

"Pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org package" doesn't honor --trusted-host and makes SSL certificate invalid behind the proxy. Is there anyway to validate certificates to pip install packages ? I'm using python 3.6.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix pip install certificate issue on Windows with Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880259/how-can-i-fix-pip-install-certificate-issue-on-windows-with-python-2-7)

Comment: I'm using pip 9 with latest python 3.6

Comment: Upgraded pip to latest version. Yet, it doesn't solve the purpose

Comment: what version of pip are you on? Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/1526703

Comment: It shows same error on 9 and 10 versions. I have seen that answer but I'm working on windows and not sure if I can use some external pip upgrade.