# install numpy and pandas on 1and1 shared hosting python

Tags: python, ssl, installation, pip, shared-hosting

I've installed python 2.7.14 on my 1and1 shared hosting server using the following tutorial: http://geeksta.net/geeklog/python-shared-hosting/
it works and has a bunch of the modules that I use.  However, i'd like to have numpy and pandas on this installation as well.

I'm having all sorts of issues, but  the most basic one is when typing:

```
pip install numpy
```

which leads to the following error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

So it looks like maybe it's failing because I don't have SSL installed, but all the suggestions for installing SSL seems to require sudo (which I can't access root on a shared host).

A second question is that I'm wondering about is if I need to use a virtualenv or not.  I'm new to this but it seems like it will allow me to install things, but again I tried to install virtualenv (as stated in the tutorial):

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

but I get the same sort of SSL error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenvwrapper/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper
```

any help that can direct me in the right direction to get these modules installed would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**Updated to ask additional approach** Given the issue seems to be not being able to download a python package on a https site (b/c SSL isn't available), is it possible for me to download the package manually using my webbrowser then FTPing the file into my server filesystem and then using SSH commands to install the modules?  If so, any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: There is no way around that — you have to recompile OpenSSL and then Python. It'd be simpler to ask you hosting provider to upgrade.

Comment: @phd so I'm not sure what that entirely means.  Is that something I can do on my shared host?

Comment: You can recompile OpenSSL and Python, but it's hard. You better ask [1and1 support](https://contact.1and1.com/contact?origin=help-center) to resolve the problem.

Comment: @phd okay thanks.  Can you provide a little more info for me?  Sounds like OpenSSL is a Unix/Linux thing.  So this needs to be recompiled before I install python?  Or do I need to recompile python as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out.  Basically, downloading each package manually from their various websites and ftp-ing them to the shared host and then unzipping and installing them manually is what worked for me.  This avoids having to connect to an SSL site to download the file on the shared host.

for numpy:

1. I downloaded the source file (numpy-1.14.2.zip) for numpy from here: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files
2. FTP that to the python folder in my shared host.
   unzipped it

   `unzip numpy-1.14.2.zip`
3. then ran setup.py from inside the numpy-1.14.2 folder

   `python setup.py install`

Then I repeated this for pandas and it's dependencies:

- setuptools
- NumPy: 1.9.0 or higher
- python-dateutil: 1.5 or higher
- pytz: Needed for time zone support

Comment: It did not work on Namecheap shared hosting. It asked to install Cython first and then broke due to some C++ toolchain issue