# Can't install django on mac

Tags: python, django, openssl, pip

Im trying to install django but I keep getting this error

```
Collecting django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

im doing `pip install django`

But for some reason its not working

tried upgrading pip but get this:

```
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.0 is available.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: tried that but didn't work

Comment: try this `https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-django-on-mac-or-linux/`

Comment: this worked thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)