# Install twisted under CentOS6

Tags: python, centos, pip, twisted

When I try to install a package, I have this error :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted>=16.0.0 (from matrix-synapse==0.27.4) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for Twisted>=16.0.0 (from matrix-synapse==0.27.4)

So I try to install Twisted : pip install twisted
But I get this error :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twisted (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for twisted

I'm working under CentOS6 and python2.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: You have to upgrade everything related to SSL: OpenSSL, python, pip.

Comment: did you try it in virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Use --verbose option with pip to see exact issue.

Sometimes pip unable to install twisted because of missing library called "libbz"

you can install libbz by below commands.

```
yum install libbz2
yum install libbz2-devel
```

Also install bzip

```
yum install bzip2
yum install bzip2-devel
```