# Error upgrading pip or using it in any capacity. SSLError: ("bad handshake

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pip

So I am using python 2.7 on a rasberry pi and am trying to install a virtualenv. So when I type:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

I get this long error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run wb.build(autobuilding=True)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
hashes)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
stream=True,

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)

File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I also tried to upgrade pip as it was out of date, but was met with a similar error.

The version I am on is 9.0.1. I looked around a bunch of forums but could not really figure out what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: This seems like it's related to [this](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4381) Python Requests library issue.

Comment: Hmm, could be related to an outdated TLS version. Try upgrading `pip` by not using `pip`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703).

Comment: @Anupam I tried that but unfortunately, I receive the same issue.

Comment: what version of pip are you on after upgrading? `pip -V`

Comment: I cannot upgrade. That is part of the problem, I have tried many commands but I am still on 9.0.1. I actually deleted pip in attempts to re-download it but now I cannot even download it due to the same error.