# Installing Flask application

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am following [this tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/packaging/) to set up a Flask application.

I am up to the step:

> pip install --editable .

When I run this I get the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from flaskr==0.0.0) (from versions: )
>     No matching distribution found for flask (from flaskr==0.0.0)

How do I install the application?

Comment: Solution to my problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --editable
```

This requires being run at root directory. Make sure you are running it at root directory. In your case that is **flaskr/** the main folder of your project.

Comment: I am running it from the root directory