# trouble installing jupyter lab with pip or conda - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel

Tags: python, pip, conda, jupyter-lab

trouble installing jupyter lab - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel

```
pip install jupyterlab
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000277F1AB8C18>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ipykernel/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipykernel (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ipykernel (from notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab)
```

After visiting [this Github page](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4417)

I checked the pip version:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

and the ipykernel version:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts>conda list ipykernel
```

I tried conda forge but still didn't work

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F03B89DE10>, 'Connection to repo.continuum.io timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))",),)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem. In my case (Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.5.2) the command

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

resulted in a similar error. After reading this page

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab

I tried this command and it worked

```
python3 -m pip install jupyterlab
```

I hope it can help!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have many python environment, so, you maybe need to specify a explicit version for python and retry to install it by follow:

```
python3 -m pip install jupyterlab
```

It worked for me, too. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If `python3 -m pip install jupyterlab` is not working try `py -m pip install jupyterlab` that works for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
I have received the same error. I was trying to upgrade jupyterlab on mint linux.

Following worked for me:

python3 -m pip install jupyterlab

Comment: This answer is similar or exact to other answers already suggesting the use of `pip`.

Comment: This answer is similar or exact to other answers already suggesting the use of `pip`.

Answer (score -2):

If you are on Windows OS: `python -m pip install jupyterlab`

On MAC OS or Linux: `python3 -m pip install jupyterlab`

Comment: All the other answers already suggest doing `pip`install` or similar.  This answer adds no value to the existing Q&A.