# Python SSL Error 748 with !pip

Tags: python, pip

I am installing packages like I normally do with Spyder inside the Ipython Console using the !pip, however in the last day I am getting this message:

```
 !pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scrapy/: 
  There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: 
  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) - 
  skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Scrapy (from 
 versions: )
  No matching distribution found for Scrapy
```

Comment: have you set pypi.python.org as a trusted source?

Comment: Yes I did in one and same error. Why all of a sudden I am shut out from this?

Comment: try specifying a cert when attempting to install a package with: "!pip --cert path/to/cert install Scrapy

Comment: Where do I find the cert path

Comment: download the one here http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and then specify the path to it on your machine

Comment: What pip version? `pip -V` See if its related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49748063/1526703)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))`