# Pip not installing anything

Tags: python, macos, pip

When I do
`pip install Flask` or
`pip install click` or
 pretty much `pip install <anything>` returns the same error :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for Flask

Same error for any virtual environment I may have created.
I'm on Mac OS, using Python 3.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Comment: Python.org sites have stopped supporting TLS v1.0 and v1.1. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Latest version is 10+, check your version using **`pip --version`**

Comment: This did it! Thanks!