# Python Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib3>=1.15

Tags: python, api

I am trying to install a python package from this API: https://github.com/CrowdEmotion/crowdemotion-api-client-python

Following the instructions inside the link, I was told to install the package by typing this to the terminal:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID.git
```

However, this error won't stop to appear:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib3>=1.15
 (from crowdemotion-api-client-python==1.0.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib3>=1.15 (from crowdemotion-api-client-python==1.0.0)
```

I do have the last version of urllib3 installed in my computer, so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: can you do a `pip freeze | grep urllib3` and update your question with the result

Comment: The result threw up the same: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib3>=1.15 (from crowdemotion-api-client-python==1.0.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib3>=1.15 (from crowdemotion-api-client-python==1.0.0)

Comment: when you run `pip freeze`? that doesn't sound correct

Comment: after I run pip freeze yes

Comment: maybe try `pip uninstall crowdemotion-api-client-python` and then try running it

Comment: it says not installed cannot uninstall

Comment: how about `pip install urllib3==1.22`

Comment: Are you able to install other packages without a problem? It's possible you're running into the issue described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th?noredirect=1&lq=1 if it's happening across the board.