# unable to install libraries with pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
```

Not just Flask, i am not able to install anything with pip3. How to fix this?

Comment: Try the `-v` argument and look out for any more detailed error message.

Comment: Any more details?
Internet works on the machine you're using pip3 on ? If you ping google.com, for example ?
What OS? How does the command you run look like ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49748063/6494927

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)