# Can't instal virtualenv on MacOS SSL/TSL issue

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to install python virtualenv on my mac, but every time I do:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

I get:

```
Collecting virtualenv
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

I've been through a lot of pages reading and trying stuff, but none of those solved the problem. So I decided to ask here.

Have you guys been there? What did you do to get it installed and working?

Comment: What version of `pip`? There is a macOS OpenSSL issue with the new [Python warehouse](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html#Migrating), so you might have to upgrade `pip` to `9.0.3+` with `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Comment: It's pip 9.0.1 and the mac is on version 10.13.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running on macOS `10.12`+ and an older version of `pip` (< `9.0.3`), you might be running into the TLS1.2 issue mentioned in the [Python warehouse blog entry](https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html#Migrating). To solve this, you need to update `pip` to `9.0.3`+ by running:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for the accurate and quick answer