# still cannot install autologin - TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION

Tags: python, ssl, pip, autologin

Trying to install [autologin](https://pypi.org/project/autologin/) on macOS 10.13.6 with

`pip3 install -U --upgrade autologin`

My Python version: 
`Python 3.5.3`

My pip3 version:
`pip 18.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)`

I should be up to date concerning python and pip so that answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) should not apply to my problem.

When I run `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3`

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0   312k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  299k
The directory '/Users/xx/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/xx/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 728kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
Successfully installed pip-18.0`

May I have overseen anything? what else can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to overcome the TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION error by updating to Python 3.7:

`brew install pyenv`

since zip something was missing I installed

`xcode-select --install`

Then I could

`sudo pyenv install 3.7.0`

Then I created a virtual env

`virtualenv --python=/Users/bileser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/bin/python3.7`

Another problem arises now when setting up python-crfsuite being part of autologin, but that is not part of the question. One question should handle ONE thing