# "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate" using pipenv install

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I'm trying to use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in a new Django project. However, if I try to `pipenv install django`, I get an error confirming the SSL certificate:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:wemap kurtpeek$ pipenv install django
Installing django...
Collecting django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping

Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

I've recently run a `brew upgrade`; here are my Pipenv and Python versions:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:wemap kurtpeek$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2018.7.1
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:wemap kurtpeek$ python --version
Python 3.7.0
```

I've tried the answer of [Not able to install Python packages [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version) but this essentially didn't do anything as my `pip` version was already up-to-date:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:wemap kurtpeek$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1604k  100 1604k    0     0   583k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  583k
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

I am running MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6, so this does indeed seem to be caused by the TLS 1.0 deprecation issue described in ['pip install' fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies/49748494#49748494). But how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this by upgrading my Macbook Pro to macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6). Now I can `pipenv install django`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:wemap kurtpeek$ pipenv install django
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Installing django...
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/wemap-X_Ia-lVq/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/wemap-X_Ia-lVq/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django)

Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (71a00b)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (71a00b)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 2/2 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```