# Having issues using pip install pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to install pandas in cmd, I keep receiving the error:

> "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for jupyter:

I have spent a few hours looking for, and trying, different solutions for this error. If anyone can help me, it will greatly be appreciated. I am new to python and I am trying to expand my data analysis capabilities.

Comment: You're using IPython.

Comment: can you post what exact commands you are trying and some details about your environment (operating system, version of Python)?

Comment: Please describe your environment and what you've tried. Also, I recommend the Anaconda distro if you are having trouble getting everything setup and are using Windows.

Comment: Python 3.7.1
Windows 7
Latest version of Anaconda

in cmd: pip install pandas

also tried: pip install pandas_datareader

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pipenv with pip3 instead of pipsi  , refer to the link below for more info : 
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/994

your question may also be related to ['pip install' fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies)

So please try :

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```