# Pynput on Mac Os. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger, pynput

I need step by step instructions on how to download and import pynput into python 3.6 on Mac Os.

Comment: Have you tried [`pip install pynput`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, thats when I got this error. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynput (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pynput

Comment: running `pip install pynput` installs `pynput-1.4.2` on my mac running High Sierra, anaconda python version 3.6. Can you paste what you ran in your question?

Comment: MacBook-Air-2:~ verdenstudent1509$ pip install pynput
Collecting pynput
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pynput/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynput (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pynput

Answer (score 0):

The SSL error that pip is reporting hints that your version of pip might be out of date, since its referencing TLS v1 being used and Python.org has [deprecated use of TLS v1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html) in their ssl library (search for PROTOCOL_TLSv1 on that page).

Check your pip version with:

`pip --version`

If your version is older than `9.0.3` its time to upgrade (see [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2018-April/032114.html) for why).
Upgrade using:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

These SO questions also touch on this:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies/49748494#49748494)
- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

And as a final bit of advice, I recommend learning about [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) for managing python projects with different dependencies on interpreter versions and libraries. [Here's a good read](https://gioele.io/pyenv-pipenv) as to why you might want these in your life. Best of luck!