# Not able to install packages with pip3 in python3 [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openssl, macos-mojave

I tried to install some python3 packages using pip3, but after typing

```
pip3 install <package_name>
```

Terminal displays: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement **package_name** (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for **package_name**.

I've been searching for some similar issues in StackOverflow, but after reading [Not able to install Python packages [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)
and
['pip install' fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies?noredirect=1&lq=1) , I tried those possible solutions (basically upgrading pip3: '*curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3*') , but the problem is still remaining. I tried it with pip and pip3; I updated setuptools too; I also upgraded OpenSSL. Nothing changed.

I don't know if it has anything to do with OpenSSL (I'm using macOs Mojave), but I tried and I don't know how to solve it. Anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: Which package do you want to install? Also, do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: Have you tried with another package? When I have had this error is because the package I wanted to install wasn't able in pip with that name

Comment: I'm trying to install pyatspi (tried python-atspi too), but I already tried with some other packages and I had the same problem. I don't really know if it's a pip problem with some or with all packages... And, obviously, I have at-spi installed.