# SSL certificate issues preventing pip package installs on windows

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate

I installed Python 3.8 from the [python.org downloads site](https://www.python.org/downloads/) onto my 64-bit Windows machine today. Shortly thereafter, I attempted to install the [pyodbc package](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) using pip from a command console opened as an administrator:

```
pip install pyodbc
```

The following error broke my connection on several attempts:

> 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   (_ssl.c:1108)')': /simple/pyodbc/

(I don't believe these issues are specific to the pyodbc package, but that just happens to be the package I've been trying to install). After some googling I tried

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyodbc
```

after which I received the error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyodbc (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyodbc

Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1393860), I decided to execute

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

after which I received the error

> next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Python 3.8 is a fresh install, as is pip (which shows as version 19.2.3). Nevertheless there seems to be a problem confirming SSL certificates. How can I get pip installs working?

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues:

1. You are behind a proxy/firewall or using an endpoint antivirus that messes with your CA cert store. Your `--trusted-host` is a workaround for that
2. [`pyodbc`](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) doesn't support Python 3.8 yet.