# Python 3.5.1: Unable to install gitpython package using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gitpython

I want to issue the Git command `git pull` from Python script to get the files from Git and update my local folders. For this I am trying to install `gitpython` package in my machine.

Python Version used is 3.5.1
OS is Winoows 10

The following two commands gave the same error.

```
python -m pip install gitpython
```

or

```
pip install gitpython
```

Error:

```
Collecting gitpython
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gitpython (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gitpython
```

Why am I getting this error? How can this be resolved?

Adding an update to this question:

Actually I am getting the above mentioned error while trying to install any package (`gitpython` or `cx_Oracle` or `sci-kit`).

Comment: Does `python --version` really show 3.5.1?

Comment: Yes. It shows Python 3.5.1

Comment: Can you try to do `python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/8c/4543981439d23c4ff65b2e62dddd767ebc84a8e664a9b67e840d1e2730d3/GitPython-3.0.5-py3-none-any.whl`?

Comment: I tried it and got this error. "ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)" What does this command do?

Comment: This command tries to download and install the `GitPython` whl file directly (usually `pip` will check on pypi and then choose a file automatically). Did you also get the same `SSL` error before or any other output except the one you posted in your question?

Comment: I did not get the SSL error before. I got only that error, which I posted in the question.

Comment: more information about the OS and its arch! and add that to the question for future readers please

Comment: OS is Windows 10. I am unable to interpret what you information you expect by "arch". Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

I would make sure you have a good up-to-date version of pip. Have a look over doing that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies). 
Try installing GitPython again after that, making sure that you have the required permissions when you run the command.