# Why can't I install python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, proxy, pip

**Context**:

I am installing the packages from a cloned repo with pip.

**What I was doing when I ran into problems:**

`python3 -m pip install --proxy "http://internal.url:8080" --upgrade pip` //Update pip and set proxy server

`pip install -r requirements.txt` // install packages

**Result**:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F6DF6CB7C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /simple/azure-mgmt-resource/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azure-mgmt-resource (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azure-mgmt-resource (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))`

**My System**: 
- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.3rc1
- Pip 20.1

**I've updated pip**:
Some S.O. answers say that the issue is a need to update pip.  I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies/49748494#49748494), which called for:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

The result was:

```
C:\PythonApps\carrieralloc-poc>curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:55 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to bootstrap.pypa.io port 443: Connection refused
```

"connection refused" is a theme here.

**[This blog suggested](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/) that perhaps my ip address was blacklisted (doubtful as I'm using a corporate proxy)**
But I tried his suggestion and ran `curl https://pypi.org`

The results: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to pypi.org port 443: Connection refused`

**I got to wondering if my proxy is set correctly**:

I can't find a command for checking my proxy.

Any pointers?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to turn off my corporate VPN.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

You're on windows, right?

I imagine you would get the same if you tried to use powershell to do the same thing.

Try this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.google.ca
```

If the command above is successful, you should expect a HTTP response, otherwise it should error out like the rest of your stuff.

Try running this powershell command to retrieve your proxy address:

```
[System.Net.Webproxy]::GetDefaultProxy()
```

Comment: Thanks @moosearch. The Invoke-WebRequest command returned a 200 response.  Worked ok.

Comment: Running the GetDefaultProxy command returned nothing:
Address               :
BypassProxyOnLocal    : Fals
BypassList            : {}
Credentials           :
UseDefaultCredentials : Fals
BypassArrayList       : {}

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows 10.

Comment: @mike_butak Did you try the invoke-webrequest with pypi? Also, try running 
the following powershell command
```Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"``` to retrieve your proxy server. I think you may have to talk with your sysadmin to see if they're blocking pip in any way or fashion

Comment: LOL, the problem was that I needed to turn off my VPN.  (I'm WFH via VPN.)  Thanks for your time helping me!

Comment: @mike_butak My work environment blocks any pip traffic and doesn't allow internet access unless it's connected to the VPN for the work-issued machines. Glad to know that your solution ended up working for you