# Failed to install packages from artifactory

Tags: python, pycharm, artifactory

Tying to install packages from Artifactory in PyCharm and getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: none)
```

I went to Settings -> Project Interpreter -> + -> Manage Respositeries and entered the URL of the repository. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can be a result of many issues:

1. For some reason Artifactory is not responding to your requests or you cannot reach it. Are you able to connect to Artifactory using a web broweser/cURL?
2. Using an old version of pip (see this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies/49748494#49748494))
3. The package you're trying to install (matplotlib) is not available for your Python version
4. The package is not present in Artifactory. Make sure you you are using either:

   - [Remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories) which is proxying the pypi repository
   - [Virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-VirtualRepositories) which contains a remote repository proxying the pypi repository