# Python Pip: pip install cannot find a version that satisfies a requirement - despite present in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, python-poetry

## Python3 Pip error + Poetry Packaging

I am working in a python library that I am trying to publish to TestPypi. So far, there have been no issues with publishing my **Poetry** builds.

For context, as a beginner, I come from these websites :

1. https://python-poetry.org/docs/
2. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

The only issue that has arose is that dependencies listed in my pyproject.toml are not accounted for when installing the package with pip install.

I have attempted at updating `setuptools` and `pip` but I have done so to no avail.

My goal is to have clean dependency installation without the versioning errors.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies) is the main solution I have tried.

#### pyproject.toml

*I hid my real names.*

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "package-name"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "<desc>"
authors = ["<myname> <myemail>"]
license = "MIT"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
beautifulsoup4 = {version = "4.11.1", allow-prereleases = true}
recurring-ical-events = {version = "1.0.2b0", allow-prereleases = true}
requests = {version = "2.28.0", allow-prereleases = true}
rich = {version = "12.4.4", allow-prereleases = true}



[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = {version = "22.3.0", allow-prereleases = true}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

As the installer iterates through a dependency, it will return this error depending on whichever one is ordered first. (*Throughout my monkey-patch-like attempts at fixing this, I was able to change the order of installation by modifying the strictness of each dependency version*)

#### the error pip returns

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.28.1 (from homeworkpy) (from versions: 2.5.4.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==2.28.1
```

- I have tried changing the strictness of the versions. (I removed the ^)
- Switching to Poetry as a manager was also an attempt. My previous attempts were manual.
- I have verified that the builds are corresponding to the correct builds previously published.

For extra info: I am building on a Github Codespace in which I run on `18.04.1-Ubuntu`

Would anyone have any knowledge to spare of an issue like this? I am quite new to packaging and building, and I have had some success in most parts except for dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Main Error

TLDR; Pip tries to resolve dependencies with TestPypi, but they are in another index (Pypi). Workarounds at end of answer.

The fact that I am publishing to **TestPypi** is the reason this has happened. I will explain why what I did made this error appear, and then I will show how you, from the future, may solve this.

### Difference between **Pypi** and TestPypi

**Pypi** is the Python Package Index. It's a giant index of Python packages one may install from with `pip install`.
**TestPypi** is the Python Package Index designated for testing and publishing without touching the real Package Index. It can be useful in times when learning how to publish a package. The main difference is that it is a completely separate repository. Therefore, what's on **TestPypi** may not be exactly what's on **Pypi**.
My research was limited, so if I confused anyone, the main difference is that they are two different Package Indexes. One was made for testing purposes.

I published my package to **TestPypi** and set my **pip install** to install from that repository. *Not **Pypi**, but **TestPypi**.*

### Why dependency resolution failed

When I defined my project's dependencies, I defined them based off of their Pypi presences. Most dependencies are present in Pypi. **Not** TestPypi. This meant that when I asked for *my* package from TestPypi, pip only looked at TestPypi, and the pip installer workflow fell out to a pattern like this:

0.5. Set fetching repository to TestPypi and **Not** Pypi.

1. Pull package from TestPypi
2. Install and examine dependencies
3. Find first dependency (e.g. Beautifulsoup4)
4. Pull dependency from TestPypi
5. Successfully install Beautifulsoup4
   -. This is because beautifulsoup4 *is* actually present in the TestPypi.
6. Move on to another dependency (e.g. rich)
7. Fail to pull from TestPypi
   -. Rich is not present in TestPypi.
8. Return dependency not found.

#### Why some dependencies oddly worked

As you see in workflow step **5.**, the **beautifulsoup4** package was found on the TestPypi. (Someone had put it up there).
[image to TestPypi page with beautifulsoup4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9IKw.jpg)
However, as you see in step **7.**, **Rich** is not found on the TestPypi index. This issue occurs because I set my repoistiroy to install from TestPypi because my that is where my package was held. This caused pip to use TestPypi. for every single dependency as well.

### How I got around it.

I got around it by using TestPypi to verify accurate build artifact publishing, and then I jumped to *Normal* Pypi to test installation and dependency installation.

## Workarounds

##### Install from TestPypi

`python3 -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ <package name>`

##### Install from Pypi (by default)

`python3 -m pip install <package name>`

##### Install package from TestPypi but dependencies from Pypi

The [Python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-testpypi/#using-testpypi-with-pip) Docs explains this very well.

> If you want to allow pip to also download packages from PyPI, you can specify --extra-index-url to point to PyPI. This is useful when the package you’re testing has dependencies:

`python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ your-package`

Comment: wonderful, thanks a lot! The last command works perfectly.