# unable to install Smartsheet python sdk

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am not able to install the sdk for smartsheets, i get the following error when i execute the command $pip install smartsheet-python-sdk

error: Could not find a version that satisifies the requirement smartsheet-python-sdk
error: No matching distribution found for smartsheet-python-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that upgrading `pip` would fix your problem. See these other posts for more info:

- ['pip install' fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies)
- [ExceptionError post](https://exerror.com/solved-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement)