# Pip Installation Error - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I am trying to install [molgrid](https://github.com/gnina/libmolgrid) library. According to [github](https://github.com/gnina/libmolgrid) and [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/molgrid/) pages
Pip installation like below.

```
pip install molgrid
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code. When I type `pip install molgrid` I am getting the following error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement molgrid
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for
> molgrid

[image]

Right now, my env's libraries list:

```
python -m pip list

Package            Version
------------------ ---------
atomicwrites       1.4.1
attrs              22.1.0
biopython          1.79
certifi            2022.6.15
charset-normalizer 2.1.0
colorama           0.4.5
condacolab         0.1.3
idna               3.3
imageio            2.21.0
importlib-metadata 4.12.0
iniconfig          1.1.1
joblib             1.1.0
networkx           2.6.3
numpy              1.21.6
packaging          21.3
Pillow             9.2.0
pip                22.2.1
pluggy             1.0.0
py                 1.11.0
pyparsing          3.0.9
pyquaternion       0.9.9
pytest             7.1.2
PyWavelets         1.3.0
requests           2.28.1
scikit-image       0.19.3
scikit-learn       1.0.2
scipy              1.7.3
setuptools         40.6.2
threadpoolctl      3.1.0
tifffile           2021.11.2
tomli              2.0.1
torch              1.12.0
torchaudio         0.12.0
torchvision        0.13.0
typing_extensions  4.3.0
urllib3            1.26.11
zipp               3.8.1
```

**Question:** How can I install molgrid lib in Visual Studio Code.

**Note1:** Installation works fine in Google Colab

**Note2:** There is a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies) but those answers are related to Linux, I couldn't find the any Visual Studio Code IDE related answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this package, we can find the `.whl` file in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/molgrid/0.5.2/#files).

[image]

> molgrid-0.5.2-py3-none-**manylinux**_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

From it's file name, we can know that it only provides the installation package of **Linux** system, so please use **Linux** instead of Windows.

Comment: I wish they would add information to the readme like it only works on Linux distributions and don't waste the developers' time. One more question, If I use Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu, will `pip install molgrid` properly work?

Comment: It seems that I have to ask the package designer about this problem. I got this information in the `.whl` file in pypi, which is also not feasible on my windows. Ubuntu is the distribution of liunx, which should be feasible.